# How to identify devices that are being targets of attempts of SNMP unsuccessful queries due wrong communities?

Tags: networking, snmp, mib

Using SNMP queries to the MIB-II objects, how to identify devices that are being targets of attempts of SNMP unsuccessful queries, since these queries inform wrong communities?

Answer (score 0):

It can be made through snmpInBadCommunityNames object.